# Datetime in ISO format with milliseconds to 000

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

My code `datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")).isoformat()` prints the following format `'2020-03-17T16:54:53.559415+01:00'`

BUT I want the milliseconds to be 0000 `'2020-03-17T16:54:53.000+01:00'`.

I tried already to use `replace(miliseconds=0)` but it removes the miliseconds completly from the printed string.

Comment: Use `strftime`, manually specifying the format, and adding `.000` for milliseconds in there…?

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as was pointed out this is a trivial formatting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `.replace(microsecond=0)` to zero out the milli-(and micro-)seconds. Then just specify the right `timespec` for `isoformat`, `'milliseconds'`:

```
nowzeroed = datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(microsecond=0)
nowberlin = nowzeroed.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin"))
nowformatted = nowberlin.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
```